# Maximum concurrent operations on couchbase single bucket

Tags: database, couchbase

I’m building a server for customers where each customer need to have each access to a database for serving his/her clients.
So my thought was to assign each customer to a specific bucket but just to find out now that a single couchbase only serve maximum of 10 buckets as recommended. But now, i don’t know if sharing a single bucket across my customers using their ID combining with the collection documents name they are creating as namespace in document type will affect the performance of all customers due to heavy operation by each customer clients on a single bucket.
I will also appreciate any database platform that can also handle this kind of project at large that performance of one customer will affect others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect the system to be heavily loaded, the activities of one user will affect the activities of another user whether they are sharing a single bucket or operating in separate buckets. There are only so many cycles to go around, so if one user is placing a heavy load on the system, the other users will definitely feel it. If you absolutely want the users completely isolated, you need to set up separate clusters for each of them.

If you are ok with the load from one user affecting the load from another, your plan for having users sharing a bucket by adding user ids to each document sounds workable. Just make sure you are using a separator that can not be part of the user id, so you can unambiguously separate the user id from the document id.

Also be aware that while Couchbase supports multiple buckets, it tends to run best with just one. Buckets are distinctly heavyweight structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my thought too